# The ui:repeat tag outputs itself on the generated html

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

The following code outputs the ui:repeat tag on the genereated html, and its breaking my layout.

```
<nav role="navigation" class="f_left f_xs_none d_xs_none t_xs_align_l"> 
    <ul class="horizontal_list main_menu clearfix">
        <ui:repeat value="#{categoryBean.rootCategories}" var="cat">
            <li class="relative f_xs_none m_xs_bottom_5">
                <a href="#{cat.url}" class="tr_delay_hover color_light tt_uppercase">
                    <b>#{cat.name}</b>
                 </a>
            </li>
        </ui:repeat>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here the Output generated by the code above:

```
<nav role="navigation" class="f_left f_xs_none d_xs_none t_xs_align_l"> 
    <ul class="horizontal_list main_menu clearfix"><ui:repeat>
        <li class="relative f_xs_none m_xs_bottom_5">
            <a href="florestal" class="tr_delay_hover color_light tt_uppercase">
                <b>Florestal</b>
            </a>
        </li></ui:repeat><ui:repeat>
        <li class="relative f_xs_none m_xs_bottom_5">
            <a href="jardinagem" class="tr_delay_hover color_light tt_uppercase">
                <b>Jardinagem</b>
            </a>
        </li></ui:repeat><ui:repeat>
        <li class="relative f_xs_none m_xs_bottom_5">
            <a href="pragas-urbanas" class="tr_delay_hover color_light tt_uppercase">
                <b>Pragas Urbanas</b>
            </a>
        </li></ui:repeat>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi BalusC I'm using Glassfish 4 and Mojarra 2.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BalusC, thanks for JSF version tip, I looked the Mojarra changelog and I found a bug on ui:repeat, I updated to Mojarra 2.2.7 and the problemn was solved.